# How to split a column in dataframe to multiple colums

Tags: python

If my dataframe is read from a csv file and looks like this

```
          0

0  XXXXXXXX

1   xOOXOAX

2  XOXOXOXX

3  XOXOXOOX

4  XOXOXXOX

5  XOXOXOOX

6  XOXOOOXX

7  XBXXXXXX
```

How do I split the one column to many columns. Each character a new column?

Many thanks

I have absolutely no idea how to do it

Comment: df[0].str.split("", expand=True)

Comment: can you let us know what your expected output should look like ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
0
XXXXXXXX
 xOOXOAX
XOXOXOXX
XOXOXOOX
XOXOXXOX
XOXOXOOX
XOXOOOXX
XBXXXXXX"""))

df['0'].str.split("", expand=True).drop(columns=[0, 9])

# Output:
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
1     x  O  O  X  O  A  X
2  X  O  X  O  X  O  X  X
3  X  O  X  O  X  O  O  X
4  X  O  X  O  X  X  O  X
5  X  O  X  O  X  O  O  X
6  X  O  X  O  O  O  X  X
7  X  B  X  X  X  X  X  X
```